# How to determine which apis to use for the code to be time efficient in spark

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What are the steps one can think through to logically conclude which api's or commands in general to use for time efficiency?

For example: Empirically, I found joining dataframes through sql api calls to be ~30% more time efficient than using native scala commands.

`df1.join(df2, df1.k == df2.k, joinType='inner')
sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.k = df2.k')`

What are the first principles involved when determining the optimal command?

Comment: What do you mean by `native scala commands`? can you give example for what commands you used to compare with spark api!

Comment: @avr I meant using `join` instead of calling sql queries with sqlContext

Answer (score 2):

Performance comparisons in big data are notoriously tricky because there are too many factors you cannot control.

Use [`explain`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) to see the logical and physical execution plans. If the two are the same for DSL vs. SparkSQL then Spark will do exactly the same work. I expect the result for both statements above to be the same and, hence, the observed difference to be due to other factors, e.g., machine resource use by other processes during the test run, pre-caching between runs, etc.

During job execution, use the Spark UI to [see what's going on](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html).